# How to export Stock Items with filters for search using Web Services

Tags: acumatica

The SOAP Message I'm sending is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.acumatica.com/typed/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:Export>
            <ns1:commands>
                <ns1:Command xsi:type="ns1:Field">
                    <ns1:FieldName>InventoryCD</ns1:FieldName>
                    <ns1:ObjectName>Item</ns1:ObjectName>
                    <ns1:Value>InventoryID</ns1:Value>
                    <ns1:Commit>true</ns1:Commit>
                    <ns1:LinkedCommand xsi:type="ns1:Action">
                        <ns1:FieldName>Cancel</ns1:FieldName>
                        <ns1:ObjectName>Item</ns1:ObjectName>
                        <ns1:LinkedCommand xsi:type="ns1:Key">
                            <ns1:FieldName>InventoryCD</ns1:FieldName>
                            <ns1:ObjectName>Item</ns1:ObjectName>
                            <ns1:Value>=[Item.InventoryCD]</ns1:Value>
                        </ns1:LinkedCommand>
                    </ns1:LinkedCommand>
                </ns1:Command>
                <ns1:Command xsi:type="ns1:Field">
                    <ns1:FieldName>Descr</ns1:FieldName>
                    <ns1:ObjectName>Item</ns1:ObjectName>
                    <ns1:Value>Description</ns1:Value>
                </ns1:Command>
            </ns1:commands>
            <ns1:filters>
                <ns1:Filter>
                    <ns1:Field>
                        <ns1:FieldName>Descr</ns1:FieldName>
                        <ns1:ObjectName>Item</ns1:ObjectName>
                    </ns1:Field>
                    <ns1:Condition>Contain</ns1:Condition>
                    <ns1:Value>TEST</ns1:Value>
                    <ns1:OpenBrackets>0</ns1:OpenBrackets>
                    <ns1:CloseBrackets>0</ns1:CloseBrackets>
                    <ns1:Operator>And</ns1:Operator>
                </ns1:Filter>
            </ns1:filters>
            <ns1:topCount>5</ns1:topCount>
            <ns1:includeHeaders>false</ns1:includeHeaders>
            <ns1:breakOnError>false</ns1:breakOnError>
        </ns1:Export>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The PHP Code with which I'm sending this message is this one:

```
<?php

$context = new Screen("<URL>", array('trace' => TRUE));
$login = new Login();
$login->name = "<LOGINUSER>";
$login->password = "<LOGINPASS>";
$context->Login($login);

$IN202500 = $context->GetSchema(new GetSchema());
$clear = $context->Clear(new Clear());
$IN202500content = $IN202500->GetSchemaResult;

$field = new Field();
$field->FieldName = $IN202500content->StockItemSummary->Description->FieldName;
$field->ObjectName = $IN202500content->StockItemSummary->Description->ObjectName;

$filter = new Filter();
$filter->Field = $field;
$filter->Condition = FilterCondition::Contain;
$filter->Value = "TEST";
$filter->Operator = FilterOperator::_And;
$filter->OpenBrackets = 0;
$filter->CloseBrackets = 0;

$export = new Export();
$export->commands = array(
    $IN202500content->StockItemSummary->InventoryID,
    $IN202500content->StockItemSummary->Description
);
$export->topCount = 5;
$export->includeHeaders = false;
$export->breakOnError = false;
$export->filters = array(
    $filter
);

$export_result = $context->Export($export);

?>
```

What I receive as response is the same results as if no filter was set. How can I filter the results for a substring of the description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the filter, how it is being sent at the end.

What is being sent is:

```
<ns1:Value>TEST</ns1:Value>
```

And instead one needs to specify a type and a namespace:

```
<ns1:Value xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">TEST</ns1:Value>
```

Otherwise, Acumatica won't detect the value for the filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
            DateTime syncDate = new DateTime(2013,1,1);
        context.IN202500Clear();            
        result = context.IN202500Export(
            new Command[]
            {                    
                IN202500.StockItemSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryInventoryID,
                IN202500.StockItemSummary.InventoryID,
                IN202500.StockItemSummary.Description,
                IN202500.WarehouseDetails.WarehouseWarehouseID,
                IN202500.WarehouseDetails.QtyOnHand
            },
            new Filter[]
            {                    
                new Filter { Field = new Field { ObjectName = IN202500.StockItemSummary.ItemStatus.ObjectName, FieldName = IN202500.StockItemSummary.ItemStatus.FieldName }, Condition = FilterCondition.Equals, Value = "Active", Operator = FilterOperator.And },
                new Filter { Field = new Field { ObjectName = IN202500.StockItemSummary.InventoryID.ObjectName, FieldName = "LastModifiedDateTime" }, Condition = FilterCondition.GreaterOrEqual, Value = syncDate.ToLongDateString(), Operator = FilterOperator.And },                    
            },
            0,false,false
        );
        //results
        foreach (string[] item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                item[0] + ";" + 
                item[1] + ";" + 
                item[2] + ";" + 
                item[3] + ";"
            );
        }
```

Comment: Does this mean I cannot filter by description but just by item status and inventory id? And the "Contain" condition does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the filters do not work properly on the default screens, they only apply to the id fields. If you create a Generic Inquiry you can specify more filters and shrink your result set down to the fields you need. Also, the Generic Inquiry screens typically run faster than the standard default screens.